# Protecting against html injection

Tags: php, html, code-injection, htmlspecialchars, html-injections

So I know that you can do `$words = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);`
in php to escape the special characters and prevent some html injection.

But I'm having trouble actually implementing it into my php code. I was reading that you have to use it before you display whatever it is you're displaying to the viewer of the site but I'm lost as to how to do this. I am a bit of a beginner with php.

So i was able to do the sql injection part but here's the part of the code where I am stuck at, as I described above.

I am trying to prevent html injection for title blog and tag

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Bpost");

echo '<div class = "blog" align = "center">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

        echo "<div class = 'tname'>";
        echo $row['title']; 
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class = "bpost">';
        echo $row['blog'];
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class = "tag">';
        echo $row['tags'];
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</br>';

        }
echo '</div>';
```

If you need sample code from my other stuff let me know. To me this seem like this was enough.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @Neal You should write a bot to do that.

Comment: @ceejayoz who says that I didn't? :-P

Comment: thanks for pointing that out guys. I really appreciate it. I keep that in mind and bring it up in my class next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `echo $row['title'];` to `echo htmlspecialchars($row['title']);` (and repeat for all the other user-generated data) and you're set.

Comment: To reiterate: always call `htmlspecialchars` when echoing a string that you can't guarantee is safe. If your string can contains HTML, that's another story, and that is a much more complicated case

Comment: Yeah I know that it doesn't protect against everything. This is just one part I wanted to add on to my extra credit project in my scripting class. We briefly talked about sql and html injection and I figured I might as well include it in this extra cred. project (even though its not required) just to go the extra mile and squeeze every bit of extra credit from my teacher.